# using this in jquery css

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to change the css of all divs with the class tab to the parent's width divided by the square root of the sibling tabs. I'm stuck because this doesn't work when selecting all tabs with jQuery. How am I supposed to solve this?
Here's the code:

```
    function remodule(){
    $(".tab").css({
            "background-color":"hsl("+"100"+","+"50%"+","+"50%"+")",
            "position":"relative",
            "max-width": ($(this).parent.width -     15)/Math.sqrt($(this).prevAll.length),
            "max-height": ($(this).parent.height - 15)/Math.sqrt($(this).prevAll.length),
            "padding":"7px"
        })
}
```

This has proven hard to google.

Comment: Have you tried opening up your console and checking for errors? One issue is that your functions don't have the requisite parentheses (i.e. `.parent` and `.prevAll` should be `.parent()` and `.prevAll()`).

Comment: You could also simplify the `background-color` into a single string, there's no point concatenating strings if you're not adding anything else into it. e.g. `"hsl("+"100"+","+"50%"+","+"50%"+")"` becomes `"hsl(100,50%,50%)"`

Comment: its undone, uses variables like parent's data and what not, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: I think if you give this a more descriptive title you'll have been luck getting answers - people scrolling through questions won't necessarily have their interest caught, and people who know exactly how to fix your problem won't say "Oh I know that!"

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario, you'll have to set the styles for each tab individually:

```
$('.tab').each(function() {
   $(this).css({ ... });
});
```

If you're setting a single property, you could use a function callback, but this is not available when passing an object of several properties:

```
$('.tab').css('max-width', function() { return $(this).parent ... });
```

So you have the choice to either iterate over all tabs once and set all properties individually, or first set the properties you can in one set-based call, and then set `max-width` and `max-height` individually using the function callbacks.

But the first option seems much more reasonable.

Comment: thanks, here's where I'm at now:
var parheight = $(this).parent().height(); works, I can log it;

var prevail = $(this).prevAll().length(); doesn't work is not a function error

Comment: It *is* not a function. `height()` is a jQuery function that calculates the height of the subject when called. `length` is a property that gives the size of the collection, you shouldn't call it. `$(this).prevAll().length` will do.